# Recursion assignment not giving correct output

Tags: c++, recursion, iteration

I have an assignment where we are performing the a + b operation with recursion. Please bear with me if this is a super easy fix because I am a newbie. Lately I have been making simple errors and just not seeing them.

We must use:

```
BASE CASE:   if ( a == 0 ) return( b ); BASE CASE:   if ( b == 0 ) return( a ); 
RECURSIVE CASE:  else  return( RecursiveAPlusB( a - 1, b - 1 ) + 2 );
```

1. My header is:

   ```
   #ifndef Adder_h
   #define Adder_h
   #include <iostream>
   using namespace std;

   class Adder{
   public:
      Adder( int a, int b );
      int getA( ) const;
      int getB( ) const;
      int RecursiveAPlusB( ) const;
      int IterativeAPlusB( ) const;
   private:
      int myValueofA;
      int myValueofB;

   };

   #endif /* Adder_h */
   ```
2. My driver is:

   ```
   #include "Adder.h"

   Adder::Adder(int a, int b){
       myValueofA = a;
       myValueofB = b;
       }

   int Adder::getA( ) const{
       return myValueofA;}

   int Adder::getB() const{
       return myValueofB;
   }

   int Adder::IterativeAPlusB( ) const{
       if(myValueofA==0)
           return myValueofB;
       else if(myValueofB==0)
           return myValueofA;
       else
           return RecursiveAPlusB();
   }

   int Adder::RecursiveAPlusB() const{
       return ((myValueofA - 1, myValueofB - 1 ) + 2) ;
   }
   ```
3. My main is (which is required by the assignment):

   ```
   #include "Adder.h"
   #include <iostream>

   using namespace std;

   int main() {
      Adder ten( 6, 4 );

     // All these calls should produce the

     // exact same answer...

     // namely, the number 10!

     cout << ten.RecursiveAPlusB( ) << endl;

     cout << ten.IterativeAPlusB( ) << endl;

     cout << ten.RecursiveAPlusB( ) << endl;

     Adder tenagain( 2, 8 );

     cout << tenagain.RecursiveAPlusB( ) << endl;

     cout << tenagain.IterativeAPlusB( ) << endl;

     cout << tenagain.RecursiveAPlusB( ) << endl;
   return 0;
   ```

   }

Please let me know where my math went wrong?! the output is 5 5 5 9 9 9, but they should all be 10. Thank you!!!

Comment: What do you mean `Recursive`? In your `RecursiveAPlusB()` there is no recursion.

Comment: My prof. gave me the recursive formula he wants and I'm just using that, so I'm not sure...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion according to the description of the assignment you should define the functions the following way. First of all you need to add one more member function to the class

```
#ifndef Adder_h
#define Adder_h
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Adder{
public:
   Adder( int a, int b );
   int getA( ) const;
   int getB( ) const;
   int RecursiveAPlusB( ) const;
   int IterativeAPlusB( ) const;

private:
   int RecursiveAPlusB( int a, int b ) const;

private:
   int myValueofA;
   int myValueofB;

};

#endif /* Adder_h */
```

And the function definitions will look like

```
int Adder::RecursiveAPlusB() const
{
    return RecursiveAPlusB( getA(), getB() );
}

int Adder::RecursiveAPlusB( int a, int b ) const
{
    if ( a == 0 ) return b;
    else if ( b == 0 ) return a;
    else return  2 + RecursiveAPlusB( a - 1, b - 1 ) ;
}
```

and

```
int Adder::IterativeAPlusB( ) const{
{
    int sum = 0;
    int a = getA(), b = getB();

    for ( ; a != 0 && b != 0; a -= 1, b -=1 )
    {
        sum += 2;
    }

    if ( a == 0 ) sum += b;
    else sum += a;

    return sum;
}
```

Take into account that the functions are valid only in case when the values are non-negative. So it is better to declare them as such that is as having type `unsigned int`.

Comment: thank you so much! I didn't realize I could make a private recursive function, so now I'll remember that from now on. Thanks again.

Comment: @brie I made a typo in the iterative function but I already updated it.:)

Answer (score 0):

In your function you use the `comma operator`:

```
int Adder::RecursiveAPlusB() const{
    return ((myValueofA - 1, myValueofB - 1 ) + 2) ;
}
```

Result of `(6 - 1, 4 - 1) = 3`.

Comment: In the assignment my prof gave us specials cases and the comma operator is just a part of it, so I'm lost. I don't know how it works, but would that be (8) + 2?

Answer (score 0):

one the way - change RecursiveAPlusB() to this:

```
int Adder::RecursiveAPlusB() const
{
    return (Adder(myValueofA - 1, myValueofB - 1 ).IterativeAPlusB() + 2) ;
}
```

Comment: wow that fixes the problem! But I have to use the special cases my prof. assigned to me, so I don't know if I can use that:-(, but maybe I am allowed Thank you!